# Rviz doesn't update rolling-window costmap origin

Tags: navigation, rviz, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I disable and then enable costmap view in rviz, it updates. But rviz itself doesn't translate cosmap update, it draws it with old origin.

It even happens for husky_navigation example.

How could I configure rviz to view rolling-window cosmap with moving origin right?

Here are 2 screenshots - first with costmap view shifted and second with correct visualisation after disable and then enable costmap view in rviz:

[image: shifted]

[image: correct]

Here is video:
[video](https://youtu.be/B455y19-dNw)

I use ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04.
I tried at different computers, on VM and without, at just-installed ROS with same result.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207755/rviz-doesn%27t-update-rolling-window-costmap-origin/) by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-04-24**:
What version of ROS, OS, and rviz are you using? Can you give a link to the `husky_navigation` example?

**Comment by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on 2015-04-26**:
Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo. http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials/Husky%20Move%20Base%20Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, I solved this problem for myself. The issue was that Rviz doesn't correctly use /move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates (of map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate type), so setting parameter `always_send_full_costmap: true` to costmap does the job.

---

Originally posted by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) with karma: 15 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0